# jQuery click event for document but ignore a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, click

I have a online Slide Show I'm working on using jQuery. I have use $(document).click event to detect when a user clicks on the page to know when to show the next bullet point in the slide or to move to the next page.

The problem I'm running into is my job had me insert a comment box on the bottom of the page and when ever someone clicks on the comment box or the save comment button it also fires the click event for the page.

Is there a way I can have the click event for the entire page but ignore it when someone clicks in the DIV the Comment box/Save button are in?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will most likely need to stop the propagation of events in your Comments div using the event object's [`stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) method:

```
$('#comments').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

if that doesn't work try using [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/):

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Same goes for the comment box/textbox, etc.

Comment: Thanks this worked great I did it on the DIV the they are in and it prevented it from happening to all of them.

Comment: Amazing... just what I was looking for!