# how to make the menu close if it is clicked out

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an menu with some values and i got someting hidden and while click on more button it shows like google more menu... if it is clicked out it is not hiding till the more menu is clicked once again

```
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="toggle('one');">More<small>▼</small></a><div class="more list" id="one" style="display:none"><a href="#">test</a> <span style="color:#329">|</span> <a href="#">test1</a> <span style="color:#169">|</span> <a href="#">test4</a></div></div>
```

Script:

```
function toggle(one)
{
  var o=document.getElementById(one);   
  o.style.display=(o.style.display=='none')?'block':'none'; 
}
```

how to make it close while the mosuse clicks on any other place other than the menus

Comment: omg, you registered with two name and ask the same question 2 times?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177582/how-to-hide-div-by-onclick-using-javascript/3179061#3179061

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [`onblur` event.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I see you've tagged this with jQuery, if that is an option, you can clear up the link a bit, like this:

```
<a href="#" class="more_link">More<small>▼</small></a>
```

And use unobtrusive script combined with event bubbling to your advantage, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".more_link").click(function(e) {
    $(this).next(".more").toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });​​
  $(".more").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $(document).click(function() {
    $(".more").hide();
  });​
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/D3w4f/), this only closes the menu if you clicked neither the menu of the toggle, e.g. clicking one of the test links will *not* close it.  If you want it to, just remove the `$(".more").click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });` portion.

It uses [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to stop the click from [bubbling up](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) to `document`, which if happens (and would if you clicked anything *else*) triggers its `click` handler, closing all the `.more` elements.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use onBlur because it's not a good accessibility approach (for example if the user is using tab to navigate the page).

Look at this solution instead:
[jQuery click event for document but ignore a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533323/jquery-click-event-for-document-but-ignore-a-div)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I let the event bubble up to the 'body' or 'html' doc and check if the target is what i want (and/or isn't contained within what i want). If the event target is not contained within your menu, then perform your desired operation (in this case, hide the div).

i.e.

`jQuery(document).ready(function(){`

```
 jQuery("html").bind("click", function(evt){
      var $target = jQuery(evt.target);
      var shouldShowMenu = $target.hasClass("menu_toggle");
      shouldShowMenu |= $target.parents(".menu_toggle, .more_list").length;
      if(!shouldShowMenu)jQuery(".more_list").hide();
 });
```

});

NOTE: your markup would needs to be extended such that the "more" href becomes has a class attribute, class="menu_toggle"