# jquery click() outside div to close div

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

**Html**

```
<div class="lang-currency-field">
   <div class="lang-currency-links">links here</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>    
     $('.lang-currency-button').click(function() {
         $('.lang-currency-field').fadeIn();
     });    

     $('.lang-currency-links').click(function() {
        $('.lang-currency-field').fadeOut();
     });    

     $('.lang-currency-field').outside('click', function(){
         $('.lang-currency-field').fadeOut();
     });    
</script>
```

I've read many articles and forums here on stackoverflow but I can't sort this out for some reasons.

How can I close/fadeOut the lang-currency-field div by clicking somewhere on the page?

It closes fine when I click on one of the links but not when I actually click out of the div.

Could you help me please? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry. This one doesn't work either.  The div fades out straight away. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use jQuery to hide a DIV when the user clicks outside of it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a handler on the div that prevents event bubbling and then delegate the "outside" handler to the document.  The handler on the div prevents clicks within the div, but not on a link from having the document-level handler close the div.  Note: you'll need to be careful of other handlers for the page that they either allow clicks to bubble up to the document (if outside the div you're closing), they take care of closing the div as well, or they take you to another page entirely (so that the div doesn't need to be closed).  If you stop propagation in handlers for elements outside the div, then the document-level handler won't be invoked.

```
<script>
     $(function() { // this will make sure the relevant DOM elements are loaded first   
        $('.lang-currency-button').click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation(); // because we don't want to close immediately after opening
            $('.lang-currency-field').fadeIn();
        });    

        $('.lang-currency-links').click(function(e) {
           e.stopPropagation(); // prevent bubbling since we don't need other handlers.
           $('.lang-currency-field').fadeOut();   
        });    

        $('.lang-currency-field').click(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation(); // prevent bubbling to document handler so div stays open when clicked inside, but not on a link
        });

        $(document).click(function() {
            $('.lang-currency-field').fadeOut();
        });
     });  
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Apparently when I include $(document).click(function() {
            $('.lang-currency-field').fadeOut();
        });
It fades out straight away. Anything I can do to prevent this? Thnak you.

Comment: Probably because the lang-currency-button is part of the document therefore it does that as well?

Comment: @Peter undoubtedly.  I'll fix -- by stopping propagation there as well.

Comment: @ tvanfosson I tried. Basically the whole page is in a main-container div. I tried it with it like $('.main-container') it doesn't work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Peter your conclusion was better than mine, and obvious enough after thinking about it.  see my updated example.

Comment: @ tvanfosson I got it. Thank you your help. It's working now!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $('page').click(function() { $('.lang-currency-field').fadeOut(); });
```

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533323/jquery-click-event-for-document-but-ignore-a-div

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it doesn't work :(  I will read the one you linked in here. Thnak you.